# "syntax error near unexpected token `elif'" error in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a script and parts of the script are as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "this_script" ] then
      this_script --parameters
elif [ "$1" == "other_script" ] then
      other_script --parameters
else
      echo "missing argument"
fi
```

When I run this script, I get the error,

```
syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
`elif [ "$1" == "SWDB" ] then'
```

1) Is it an issue with line endings? I wrote the script with Notepad++ on Windows BUT i have enabled the EOL conversions under Edit to UNIX/OSX format.

2) If not line endings, what is the error?

I am running this script in bash shell on a Redhat Linux OS.

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net would have caught this for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a semi-colon after `if [ ... ]` and before `then`, and the same with `elif`:

```
if [ "$1" == "this_script" ]; then
#                           ^
#                           here!
#                              v
elif [ "$1" == "other_script" ]; then
```

From [Bash manual - 3.2.4.2 Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> The syntax of the if command is:
>
> ```
> if test-commands; then
>   consequent-commands;
> [elif more-test-commands; then
>   more-consequents;]
> [else alternate-consequents;]
> fi
> ```
>
> The `test-commands` list is executed, and if its return status is zero,
>   the `consequent-commands` list is executed. If `test-commands` returns a
>   non-zero status, each `elif` list is executed in turn, and if its exit
>   status is zero, the corresponding `more-consequents` is executed and the
>   command completes. If ‘`else alternate-consequents`’ is present, and the
>   final command in the final `if` or `elif` clause has a non-zero exit
>   status, then `alternate-consequents` is executed. The return status is
>   the exit status of the last command executed, or zero if no condition
>   tested true.

Comment: or put it on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

The 'then' statements should be on new lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "this_script" ]
then
    this_script --parameters
elif [ "$1" == "other_script" ]
then
    other_script --parameters
else
    echo "missing argument"
fi
```

Works for me in that format.